# Code works with Jupyter(Anaconda) but not with normal Python - WHY

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

```
import keyboard

def on_key(key):
    file.write(str(key.__dict__) + "\n")
    file.flush()

file = open("./log.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8")
keyboard.hook(on_key)
```

this code works perfect with Jupyter (Anaconda) but doesnt work with normal python IDE or the python console: it just creates a log.txt file nothing more. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code execution ends the moment the end of the file is reached. If you look at the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/) of the library, you also see the example ending the code with `keyboard.wait()`. This command prevents the code from ending and being cleaned up.

Comment: thank you very much :) but why did it work in Jupyter(old code) ? o.O

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Jupyter, but I assume that it keeps a running python session going anyways. Thus it is never actually terminated at the end of the script.